# Consume web service returning list

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, class

I have a web service with webmethod like this:

**Webservice:**

```
   [WebMethod]
    public List<ProcessQueue> GetTasks(int ShopId)
    {
        List<ProcessQueue> p = new List<ProcessQueue>();
        p.Add(new ProcessQueue {shopId="shop1", process="process1"});
        p.Add(new ProcessQueue {shopId="shop2", process="process2"});   
        return p;
    }


    public class ProcessQueue
    {
        public string shopId { get; set; }
        public string process { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a windows form application which is consuming the web service:

I followed the steps described in [Consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)

**Windows form:**

```
using (var svc = new Service1SoapClient())
{
    var result = svc.GetTasks(7);
    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

Right now I am able to consume the web service but only problem I am facing is I cannot get the result as a string in my windows form application.

How would I do that. Any help?

Comment: How do you want to convert list to string?

Comment: I want to get values of shopId and process in the winform, how can i achieve that? I don not want to convert list to string.

Comment: Ok, let's say your services returned 2 rows, what's you expected output string?

Comment: I got the solution myself. Please see my updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the desired result by doing this in winform application:

```
using (var svc = new Service1SoapClient())
{
   var result = svc.GetTasks(7);
   List<ProcessQueue> Processqueue=result.ToList<ProcessQueue>();
   foreach (ProcessQueue process in Processqueue)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(process.shopId);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the client side you have to normally iterate on result, as on list at server side (you have the same type (probably) on the client:

```
using (var svc = new Service1SoapClient())
{
    var result = svc.GetTasks(7);
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        textBoxName.AppendText(String.Format("ShopId: {0}, Process: {1}\n", item.shopId, item.process));
    }
}
```